# Migrate to BLoC 7.2- Nested Streams - yield* inside other stream

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

*I'm migrating a project from Bloc 7.0 to 7.2*

I have an issue trying handle the migration of this following `Stream` since it is calling another Stream within it self :

```
 Stream<CustomerState> _mapUpdateNewsletter({...}) async* {
    try {
      [...]
      
      yield* _mapGetCustomer(); // Calling another Stream here

      Toast.showSuccess(message: successMessage);
    } ...
  }
```

Here is what the called `Stream` used to look like

```
 Stream<CustomerState> _mapGetCustomer() async* {
    try {
      final customer = await _customerRepository.getCustomer();
      yield state.getCustomerSuccess(customer);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      ApiError.handleApiError(error, stackTrace);
    }
  }
```

Here is what I migrated it to :

```
  Future<void> _onGetCustomer(
      GetCustomer event, Emitter<CustomerState> emit) async {
    try {
      final customer = await _customerRepository.getCustomer();
      emit(state.getCustomerSuccess(customer));
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      ApiError.handleApiError(error, stackTrace);
    }
  }
```

How am I suppose to call it now in Bloc 7.2 ?

```
 Future<void> _onUpdateNewsletter(UpdateNewsletter event, Emitter<CustomerState> emit) async {
    try {
     ...
     yield* _onGetCustomer; // How do I call this async future here?
      Toast.showSuccess(message: event.successMessage);
    } ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the new version of the bloc, you don't have to write stream functions. you have a function called `emit` and calling this function and passing the new state is possible from every function in your bloc. so remove `yield*` and just call `_onGetCustomer` function and from there emit your new state.

Comment: Ok but do I have to write `await _onGetCustomer` ? since it is a `Future<void>`?

Comment: Yes. `await _onGetCustomer(? ,emit);`. You have to decide where `?` comes from, I couldn't identify it in your code. But you needed it before, so I'm sure it's there.

Comment: @Sunshine if you want to  `Toast.showSuccess`  runs after state change. yes you have to await. otherwise, no it works perfect without `await`

Comment: @nvoigt I didn't understand you mean I can pass events as parameters ?

Comment: [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755611/bloc-7-2-migration-passing-parameters-inside-streams) : )