# Bloc 7.2 migration - passing parameters inside streams

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, bloc

*I'm currently migrating a project from Bloc 7.0 to bloc 7.2*

I use to have a stream which I would `yield*` inside different Streams & passing every time a different value as parameter

```
 Stream<CartState> _mapCheckCart({CART_STATUS status}) async*
{...}
```

but with BloC 7.2 I had to rewrite my stream as follow and don't know - *now* - how to pass in a parameter :

```
 Future<void> _onCheckCart(event, Emitter<CartState> emit) async {
    ...
      emit(state.checkCartSuccess(
        amounts: cart.amounts,
        status: status, // I need to pass in the status here 
      ));
     ...
  }
```

Ideally I'd like to use `_onCheckCart` like this

```
    on<CheckCart>(
        _onCheckCart(statusOnSuccess: CART_STATUS.CHECK_CART_SUCCESS));

    on<CheckCustomerInformation>(_onCheckCart(
        statusOnSuccess: CART_STATUS.CHECK_CUSTOMER_INFORMATION_SUCCESS));
```

---

`CART_STATUS` is an `enum`

`enum CART_STATUS {LOADING,READY,CHECK_CART_IN_PROGRESS, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition:

```
Future<void> _onCheckCart(event, Emitter<CartState> emit, CART_STATUS status) async {
```

Call (or rather: registration of call):

```
on<CheckCart>((ev, em) =>
    _onCheckCart(ev, em, CART_STATUS.CHECK_CART_SUCCESS));

on<CheckCustomerInformation>((ev, em) =>
    _onCheckCart(ev, em, CART_STATUS.CHECK_CUSTOMER_INFORMATION_SUCCESS));
```

Your _onCheckCart function has no type for event. You should use the proper type there.

Comment: ```Future<void> _onCheckCart(
      CartEvent event, Emitter<CartState> emit, CART_STATUS status)``` thank you I added `CartEvent` as the event type as both `CheckCustomerInformation` & `CheckCart` extend `CartEvent` - is it the right thing to do ?

Comment: yes, that's good.